# Format query to show floating decimal in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I have a query in which one of the columns has a number value that I want to divide by 1,000,000 then display to show commas and up to 10 decimal places if the calculate value has any decimal places. I am currently using this query:

```
to_char(value/1000000, 'FM999,999,990.9999999999') as Millions_Value
```

The above format gives me commas and retains the number of decimal places I want, but it unfortunately adds a decimal point at the end of whole numbers as well.

Example:

value/1000000 = 33993

formatted value = 33,993.

what I want = 33,993

For a decimal value, I get what I want and need to keep the format

Example:

value/1000000 = 0.158739

formatted value = 0.158739

value/1000000 = 10.82

formatted value = 10.82

And ideas on how to get rid of the decimal for integers?

Comment: Somewhat related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51268758/266304).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use RTRIM, e.g.

```
RTRIM(to_char(value/1000000, 'FM999,999,990.9999999999'), '.') as Millions_Value
```

will remove any trailing periods.

### EDIT

If you want to get fancy and internationalize it you need to query NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS to get the decimal separator, use the G (group) and D (decimal) specifiers in the format string, and then trim off any trailing decimal separator characters. Or in other words:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 123456789.123456789 AS N FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 123 FROM DUAL),
     cteDecimalSeparator AS (SELECT SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, 1) AS DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
                               FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                               WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS')
SELECT TO_CHAR(N, 'FM999G999G990D9999999999') AS OLD_FORMAT,
       RTRIM(TO_CHAR(N, 'FM999G999G990D9999999999'), s.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR) AS NEW_FORMAT
  FROM cteData d
  CROSS JOIN cteDecimalSeparator s
```

which returns

```
OLD_FORMAT              NEW_FORMAT
123,456,789.123456789   123,456,789.123456789
123.                    123
```

Remember: there's no kill like overkill :-)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it looks good with one trailing 0, so converting your format string to have a 0 after the decimal.  But to answer you question, I think you just need to trim it after you convert the number like this:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TO_CHAR('345676', 'FM999G999G990D9999999999'))
FROM DUAL;
```