# Format mask with leading zero for NUMBER

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Which format mask should I use to convert number data from table column `NUMBER` to char if I want to preserve one leading zero and don't know data "size"? Value could have integral and/or fractional part. All that I know - it's `NUMBER`.

Source Data (numbers)

```
.12345678901234567890
100
100.500
12345678901234567890.1234567890
```

Desired result (text)

```
0.1234567890123456789
100
100.5
12345678901234567890.123456789
```

and so on, i.e. number could have unpredictable number of digits in whole part and unpredictable number of digits in fractional part.

Comment: OK, so not really leading zeros, but keep the zero for < 1? And keep trailing zeros - which is a problem as those don't exist in the source data; how do you know the first one ends ...890 and not 8900 or 89000? Trailing zeros make even less sense than leading zeros really. If you don't need those, [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269390/266304)?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, sorry, mistype, just NUMBER

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you, bespoke format mask seems useful, my collegue also offers SELECT CASE WHEN regexp_like (column1, '^\.\d+$') THEN '0' || column1 ELSE column1 END

Comment: Yes, though at least the last element would need to be `to_char(column1)` to avoid a data type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

A `NUMBER` data type is a binary value that has no format; if you want to format the number then you will need to convert it to another data-type that can represent the numeric value with a format, such as a `VARCHAR2` data-type using the `TO_CHAR` function:

```sql
SELECT value,
       RTRIM(
         TO_CHAR( value, 'FM999999999999999999999990D99999999999999999999' ),
         '.'
       ) AS formatted_number
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT .12345678901234567890 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100.500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345678901234567890.1234567890 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | FORMATTED_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- |
> | .1234567890123456789 | 0.1234567890123456789 |
> | 100 | 100 |
> | 100.5 | 100.5 |
> | 12345678901234567890.123456789 | 12345678901234567890.123456789 |

---

> number could have unpredictable number of digits in whole part and unpredictable number of digits in fractional part.

Just increase the number of `9`s before and after the `D` decimal separator until the number of integer/fractional digits reaches your maximum precision.